# Compare U.S. tramps slang scoffing "food, something to eat," 1907

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "tramps" mean in "[compare U.S. tramps slang scoffing 'food, something to eat,' 1907"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/scarf)? I don't think it means 1. To walk with a firm, heavy step; trudge or 2. a. To travel on foot; hike. b. To wander about aimlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intended sense of "*tramp*" here is the one given by [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tramp) as:

> a person with no home, job, or money who travels around and asks for money from other people

Compare *hobo* and *beggar*. A tramp may be seeking casual, temporary work, or handouts, or both. So here "tramps slang" means "slang as used by tramps" and should have been "tramps' slang".

This sense of "tramp" was more common in the 19th and early 20th centuries than it is now. See also Robert Frost's verse "Two Tramps in Mud-time" or Mark Twain's repeated use of the term in ["The Facts Concerning the Recent Carnival of Crime in Connecticut"](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/3183).

Comment: Some decades ago, it was not uncommon for local communities here in the UK to hold a 'Tramps' Supper' as a social/fundraising event, for which people dressed up in old clothes like [this](https://www.ourmansfieldandarea.org.uk/content/mysteries/tramps-supper). Nowadays, with increasing awareness of the plight of homeless people, it would be considered tactless.

Comment: Thank you so very much for you detailed explanations!